# Is $z=0$ an essential singularity of $1/\sin(1/z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $z=0$ an essential singularity of $\dfrac{1}{\sin\dfrac{1}{z}}$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Is the function bounded in a neighbourly of $z=0$?

Answer (score 4):

For every nonzero integer $k$ the point $z_k=\dfrac{1}{k\pi i}$ is a singularity of 
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin\frac{1}{z}}.
$$
Thus $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of the  $f$. Essential singularities are isolated!

Comment: No, the opposite is true. Non-isolated singularities are necessarily essential, since a meromorphic function has isolated poles.

Comment: @Mike: An essential singularity is an isolated singularity as well! The non-isolated singularities are either cluster points of point of a natural boundary. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity

Comment: That's untrue. By definition an essential singularity is one which is neither a pole nor a removable singularity. The singularity at $0$ in this case is neither...

Comment: @Mike: By definition, an essential singularity is an isolated singularity which is neither removable nor a pole! - See also http://people.duke.edu/~ad159/files/m185/19.pdf (page 3).

Comment: This is not the definition I'm aware of (a function meromorphic on $\Bbb C\backslash\{a\}$ has an essential singularity at $a$ if it cannot be meromorphically continued to the entire complex plane); these aren't equivalent definitions. So it seems our disagreement stemmed from differing definitions. Sorry!